# ORA-12541: TNS:no hay ning·n listener

Tags: oracle, virtualbox

Tengo una maquina virtual(Virtualbox) Red-Hat con oracle donde tengo mi base de datos, el problema es que no consigo conectar mi windows7 con esta maquina virtual a traves del puerto 1521. Por ssh (22) si me deja sin ningun problema.

Estado del listener:

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 02-APR-2019 13:04:59

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                02-APR-2019 12:32:48
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 32 min. 16 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ip-10-0-2-15/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1522)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=ip-10-0-2-15.eu-west-1.compute.internal)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/home/oracle/app/oracle/admin/orcl/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Intentando conectar: conn user/passw@//ip/orcl
la respuesta es:
ORA-12541: TNS:no hay ning·n listener

No entiendo porque no funciona.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Validastes si en el firewall esta abierto ese puerto dale un `telnet ip port` desde tu windows 7. Tambien veo que el port es `1522,5500` no `1521` el por default asi que debes especificar en el string de conexion con `//ip:port/servicename`

Comment: La respuesta de TELNET:
telnet 192.168.56.12 1522
Conectándose a 192.168.56.12...No se puede abrir la conexión al host, en puerto
1522: Error en la conexión

Comment: El puerto sale 1522 porque intente cambiar-lo. El problema es que funcionan todos los demas puertos excepto 1522 o 1521, el firewall esta apagado en la maquina virtual i en windows

Comment: intentas conectar un cliente para oracle? on un cliente para red hat?

Answer (score 1):

Solo veo un listener para localhost y esta en el puerto 1522, asi que no esta escuchando para conexiones externas

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1522)))
```

Agrega un listener para la IP por la que accedes a dicha maquina virtual, por ejemplo:

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.1.100)(PORT=1521)))
```